# Override the space between the last two elements

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have footer in my site's page that hold a list of links , the last two links are social icons
[image: footer items]

and i have this css code

```
   #FooterLinks{
        width:960px;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:center;
        padding-top:10px;
        font-weight:bold;
}

#FooterLinks li{
        display:inline;

        color:White;
}
#FooterLinks li:last-child{
        border:none;
}
#FooterLinks li a {

        color:White;
        padding: 0 10px;

}
#FooterLinks li a img{

        border:none;

}
a:link{text-decoration:none;}

#FooterLinks li a:hover{
        color:Red;

}
```

this is the source code of my footer:

```
<div id="FooterLinks">
 <ul>
   <li id="fbAbout"><a href="aboutus.aspx">About Us</a></li>
   <li id="fbcareers"><a href="careers.aspx">Careers</a></li>
   <li id="fbprivacy"><a href="privacy.aspx">Privacy</a></li>
   <li id="fbterms"><a href="terms.aspx">Terms</a></li>
   <li id="fbpress"><a href="press.aspx">Press</a></li>
   <li id="fbcontactus"><a href="contactus.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
   <li id="fbfaq"><a href="faq.aspx">FAQ</a></li>
   <li id="fbgethelp"><a href="gethelp.aspx">Get Help</a></li>
   <li id="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/YOUR_USER_NAME"><img src="Imaes/Main/SocialIcons/twitter.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Twitter"  /></a></li>
   <li id="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/298542786850699"><img src="Images/Main/SocialIcons/facebook.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>

  </ul>
  <p>&copy; PlaySight Interactive Ltd. All Right Reserved</p>       
</div>
```

what should I add to the css to fix my problem?

edit : I added the source code of the footer.

Comment: Show us some html code of the footer..

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted your HTML code I can only guess at that. Assuming you have something like `#footerLinks > li > a` the following should do the trick:

```
#FooterLinks li:last-child a {
    padding: 0;
}
```

This code removes the padding for the last `li`, reducing the space in between the two social icons by 50%. If you want to remove the space altogether you can do so using the CSS selector `nth-last-child()`.

Please be aware though that the CSS selector `last-child` is not supported in many older browsers. So if you want you website to work properly in every browser you should try something else. I would make the social `li` of class `social` (or something similar) in your HTML, and then I would add some CSS code to remove the padding for that class. You can then also hide the border for those items without `last-child`. If you post your HTML code I can give an example.

Comment: Don't use inline styles.  Apply a class.

Comment: @shaharnakash: John Kurlak is right, you should use classes. Since inline styles, some other part of your code must be interfering. So find out what and use classes!

Comment: @shaharnakash: Care to accept an answer if your problem was solved?

Answer (score 0):

Add class to links you want no space:

```
  <li id="twitter"><a class='noPadding' href="https://twitter.com/YOUR_USER_NAME"><img src="Images/Main/SocialIcons/twitter.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Twitter"  /></a></li>
  <li id="facebook"><a class='noPadding' href="http://www.facebook.com/298542786850699"><img src="Images/Main/SocialIcons/facebook.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
```

and CSS:

```
.noPadding{ padding:0px;}
```